# openssl ? Join a public and a private key

Tags: certificate, openssl, public-key, private-key, pem

Basicly, I have a private PEM key and a public certificate PEM key.
They work when I use them both (but don't work if I only use one of them).

I use and this works:
wget --no-check-certificate --private-key=dev-private.pem --certificate=dev.pem https://???.???.???.???
(This is self-signed certificate signed by java keytool. I have acces to this keystore.)
I also produce a jks and it's work great in browser.

The problem is one of my application I neeed to use a certificate and he only support 1 PEM key (only support certicate with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" header).
I don't have figure out how to make 1 PEM key containing private and public key.

Did there is some way to join both for make 1 big PEM key ?

They're so many command line for openssl.

Thank you

Comment: I think I figure out.. but I still need help.
Both key aren't build from request, so, I can't merge them.

First I need explain what I want to do.
I'll also explain step by step everything... so someone will be able to help me.


I have 2 different computer: one Windows with javatool and one other Linux with openssl.
The Windows is the server-side and the linux have a third party application using pem certificate to connect.

Comment: First, on my server I generate a key for my client-side: keytool -genkey -alias _client machine name_ -keyalg RSA -keystore server.keystore -keysize 2048 keytool -certreq -alias _client machine name_ -keystore server.keystore -file req.csr This build a request "-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----". At this point I don't know what to do with the certificate request...

Answer (score 1):

Not fully sure what you are asking, but you can just join both the public and private key into a single file and that may be all you need for your application.  Just cut and past the PEM key from each of the current files into a new file.  Then point your application to the new file.  I have used that technique myself for one of my applications.

Hope this helps.

Al

Comment: I'm not fully sure myself. It's 2 key (one private and one certificate): one begin with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- MIICdgIB...(848 caracters) and -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIICR...(780 caracters) for the other. So I think I need to do some "join" on both for make a larger certificate. I do it for make a jks file but I read nothing about "join" for making an full PEM key. Perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: I think I figure out.. but I still need help.